# Shader Compiler Error - 2019.2.11 Android Build Not Working Properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

After creating a demo project, I have exported a game project for my Android device and as the game played within the device, I got shocked because of this kind of output:

[image]

There is no Canvas UI exists, there is no skybox exist and there is a black stripe in the middle of the screen.
Up to now, I have tested game within the Unity Editor and it was working perfectly.

Here are the inspector settings for the Android Build:
[image]

Now provide me some suggestions so I can solve this problem and I can test the game within my Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got a solution for my this problem. I was getting this kind of error messages in the console:

[image]

There is a shader compiler related problem that exists and I got a proper solution in this thread and I have applied and it worked for me.

[Unity 2019.2.7 build iOS crashes in Shader Compile](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2019-2-7-build-ios-crashes-in-shader-compile.757754/)